# Crypto SystemKeys folder growing out of control

Tags: iis, cryptography, remote-desktop

Help! The folder **C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Crypto\SystemKeys** is growing out of control. It is doing this on some of our servers and some desktops. We are a medium to small business and use Active Directory (not Azure AD).  I've heard that this folder is used by IIS, SQL Server, Remote Desktop Licence Server (maybe other things too?).   My guess is it has something to do with Remote Desktop as I've not seen this problem with any computer that hasn't been using Remote Desktop. I've heard that some of the keys in this folder are important so you can't just delete it. Anyone have any idea what to do to get it to stop, what causes it, or how to clean it up?

Here my file properties:
[image]

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Tons of previous discussions are out there, https://superuser.com/questions/538257/why-are-there-so-many-files-in-c-programdata-microsoft-crypto-rsa-machinekeys

Comment: This is a slightly different location, the SystemKeys folder, not the RSA folder.  I've looked at some of the previous discussions but haven't found anything that works.

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer to this question.  Turns out in my case it was because of an application writing to this directory. Contacted them and they are implementing a fix in the next release (October 2021).  In the mean time, I've deleted the extra keys in the folder.  So far no issues.

Comment: could you please tell us which application is the culprit?

Comment: ManageEngine Desktop Central

Comment: @ajr How-to discover that *ManageEngine Desktop Central* writes to the directory ? support link ?

Comment: @Kiquenet If you're a customer, you can contact them.  I discovered it because I had a computer that had nothing on it.  I was watching that folder because I had problems with the size on other computers.  As soon as MEDC was installed, it started growing.  Anyway, MEDC implemented a fix and seems fine now.